# Fetching data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, php, phpmyadmin

Wanna fetch data from 3 tables by mysql query to display in feed. But stack. My query is

```
SELECT f.leaderId, f.followerId, c.ccId, c.ccTitle, c.ccCity, c.ccCountry, c.ccFlag, c.uId, c.ccStartingDate, c.ccCreatedAt, l.uId, l.ccId
FROM followingrelations f, conferencecreate c, likesbyuser l
WHERE f.followerId = 'login_user_id'
      AND c.uId = f.leaderId
      AND c.ccFlag = 1
      AND c.ccStartingDate >= 'current_time_and_date_now' 
      OR l.uId = f.leaderId
GROUP BY c.ccTitle 
ORDER BY c.ccId DESC;
```

**Expectation:**

1. Want to fetch data where `uId` and `leaderId` are matched from `followingrelations` and `conferencecreate` tables respectively.
2. Beside above condition, want to fetch data also if any user likes any post. The condition I putted like this way `OR l.uId = f.leaderId`

Am I on right track?

I implemented this query but nothing displaying. Any idea how to solve this issue plz?

My database design is in following:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain again your expectations ? I absolutely don't get what you want. Also, in your query, you may want to use `SELECT ... FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id INNER JOIN table 3 ON table1.id = table3.id WHERE ...` in order to clarify your query because it's impossible to understand what your different WHERE-clauses do (joining or filtering ?)

Comment: Actually, I want to make a feed page based on my data in above tables. More specifically feed page like facebook where will get friends update status and on what they like / comments. Just want to make this. Any idea?

Comment: Dont join tables like that: "FROM followingrelations f, conferencecreate c, likesbyuser l" It produces a CROSS JOIN and you need to provide JOIN predicates in a WHERE clause. This style used to be popular like 15 years ago. It is a really bad practice, It's hard to read and even harder to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it.

```
SELECT f.leaderId, f.followerId, c.ccId, c.ccTitle, c.ccCity, c.ccCountry, c.ccFlag, c.uId, c.ccStartingDate, c.ccCreatedAt, l.uId, l.ccId
        FROM  conferencecreate c
left join followingrelations f on c.uId = f.leaderId
left join likesbyuser l on  (c.ccStartingDate >= 'current_time_and_date_now' or l.uId = f.leaderId )
        WHERE f.followerId = 'login_user_id'
        AND c.ccFlag = 1
        GROUP BY c.ccTitle 
        ORDER BY c.ccId DESC
```